# What is the difference between TRUNCATE and TRUNCATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, truncate

MySQL seems to allow `TRUNCATE table_name` and actually does truncate the table. There seemed to be a performance difference, `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` seemed to be faster. I cannot find anything on what the differences are though. Most of things I have found are on the difference between truncate and delete.

Comment: What was the performance difference? Was it negligible?

Comment: There is no difference. Read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: @Dharman yeah, a table of 10 million records that seemed to be faster with truncate table. It seemed odd for a small change to cause an impact but I am thinking there is just something else that I am not aware of that is the true cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between `TRUNCATE TABLE tbl` and `TRUNCATE tbl`. This is the same statement with both forms of the syntax perfectly correct and equally the same.

The reason why there are two ways of writing it is, because some people prefer one form over the other. It could be confused with the [`TRUNCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) function, so adding `TABLE` makes the syntax more clear.

> The TABLE keyword is optional. However, it is a good practice to use the TABLE keyword to distinguish between the TRUNCATE TABLE statement and the TRUNCATE() function. - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-truncate-table/

Comment: pretty sure the main reason `TRUNCATE` and `TRUNCATE  TABLE` came into MySQL  because of more RDMS supported this and because of SQL:2008 standard where `TRUNCATE` and `TRUNCATE  TABLE`  are valid syntax..

Comment: @raymond Why is it part of the SQL:2008 then?

Comment: We move a bit off topic now but i think because of IBM / Oracle corp involvement on the ANSI/ISO SQL standards i believe both had or still have a huge influence on the standards...  But i understand your question/point as most RDMS supported it way before the standard defined it